# How to manage many src directories in python vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I've a python project structure like this:

```
root/
  src/
    shared-libs/
      Pipenv
    app1/
      Pipenv
    app2/
      Pipenv
```

Where:

- `shared-libs`: a library shared with all app
- `app?`: some applications witch depends on shared-libs but not on other app*

My problem is how can I configure VSCode to enable completion on modules available in `shared-libs` and in my Pipenv ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're just after completion, see the [`python.autoComplete.extraPaths` setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference#_autocomplete-settings). If you want packages that are installed as part of your virtual environment in `pipenv`, then you need to make sure that you have specified the virtual environment as your Python interpreter (explicit support for pipenv will be in the next release, scheduled some time during the week of March 5).